# Align multiple dynamic HStack in VStack inside navigation View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview, vstack, hstack

Need to align this :

```
import SwiftUI


struct MainAct: View {


private let images = ["ImageSlide/first","ImageSlide/second","ImageSlide/third","ImageSlide/fourth","ImageSlide/five","ImageSlide/six","ImageSlide/seven"]

@StateObject var imageList = FireImageModel()
@State private var btPress = false
@State private var currentIndex = 0
@State var zoomed = false
private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common) .autoconnect()


var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{

      ZStack(){
            
            LinearGradient(gradient:Gradient(colors:  [Color.blue,Color.green]),startPoint: .top,endPoint:.bottom)
      
            VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:0)
            {
       
                
                HStack(spacing: 0){

                 GeometryReader{proxy in
                        
                        TabView(selection: $currentIndex){
                            
                            ForEach(0..<7){photo in
                            Image("\(images[photo])")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                        }
                        }
                        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width,height:proxy.size.height*0.55)
                    .onReceive(timer, perform: {_ in
               {currentIndex = currentIndex < images.count ? currentIndex + 1 : 0})
               
                }
            }


                 HStack{
                         Button()
                         Button()
                       }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                HStack{
       
                         Button()
                         Button()
                       }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                        .navigationBarTitle("")
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
       }
  
    }.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
     .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
    }
```

Issue is there is space after first Stack ie after imageSlider. If I remove geometry reader than the stack/image is taking rest of the empty screen (see pic) even after resizing. What a want is stacks with button should come directly below stack with image slider there should be minimum space between them like space between the stack containing buttons. Not been able to align this view.

[image: Current situation]

Comment: unrelated, but `Fourt Sample` typo.

Comment: yes changed names for pic actually :)

Answer (score 0):

It is `GeometryReader` pushes buttons down, because it is aligned first and consumes all available space.

A solution is to move GeometryReader *outside* of `VStack`, so layout would be like

```
ZStack {
  GeometryReader { gp in
    VStack {
      TabView {}.frame(height: gp.size.height * 0.55)    // << 55%

      HStack {}   // << buttons !!
      HStack {}   // << buttons !!

      Spacer()    // << push buttons up (if needed)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried this also...it removes extra space and aligned as required but one issue remains -- inconsistent space above image at top based on image size is appearing can't get rid of that image should fill the three side top left and right irrespective of image size. left and right are done but not top

Comment: One question one answer... and don't forget in future provide minimal reproducible example... it's hard guessing with not compilable code.

Comment: earlier I posted with code was closed for too much code...will note this in further Q